# Find out whether network connection is full or half duplex

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

How do I find out whether a network connection is full or half [duplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_%28telecommunications%29)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **mii-tool** :

```
$ sudo mii-tool 
eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
```

'FD' is full duplex.  'HD' would represent half.  For those who haven't seen this, it's because it generally represents a network problem -- you should always see and expect full.

If you don't have mii-tool installed, it is in the **net-tools** package:

```
$ dpkg -S mii-tool
net-tools: /usr/share/man/man8/mii-tool.8.gz
net-tools: /sbin/mii-tool
```

I believe it is included with a base install, however.

In some cases, **dmesg** will be sufficient.
Identify your local interface and check dmesg:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i duplex
[   31.920900] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

Comment: An article that gives more details: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-linux-lan-card-find-out-full-duplex-half-speed-or-mode/

Comment: @N.N.  Ah, it does also talk about `ethtool` .  Not installed by default, but the package is also named `ethtool`, for those wanting to check it out.